# How to add code before WordPress loading

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to run some codes before wordpress loading. Actually I want to check HTTP_USER_AGENT and decide send them to WordPress or redirect them to another URL.

At the moment I put my codes in the index.php file, but I'll loss them on wordpress update.

What Should I do?

---

here is the .htaccess code I'd used before:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_CLIENT_IP} !^(10\.10\.10\.10)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR} !^(10\.10\.10\.10)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED} !^(10\.10\.10\.10)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR} !^(10\.10\.10\.10)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_FORWARDED} !^(10\.10\.10\.10)
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(10\.10\.10\.10)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_CLIENT_IP} !^(10\.10\.10\.10)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_CLIENT_IP} !^(10\.10\.10\.10)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_CLIENT_IP} !^(10\.10\.10\.10)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Baiduspider|Bingbot|Googlebot|msnbot|Slurp|Teoma|YahooSeeker|YandexBot) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: is your server Apache? .htaccess works easily for this and performs much better than doing it in php, if that's an option.

Comment: @RobP: Yes, I'm using Apache and I'd used htaccess before, but no success. I want to let SearchEngines get in and redirect all other visitors to another domain.

Comment: I would suggest posting here what you tried in .htaccess and the community can help you get it right. It's made to do this type of thing. (But what you are doing is a little sketchy, by the way...)

Comment: @RobP: OK, I updated the question for you.

Comment: @RobP: I also want to know the answer of my main question...

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the validation code in template's header page probably header.php
but if you update the theme you will loose the changes you made.

Comment: Other plugins may send output before the header.php, so do not do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the init callback. From [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init).

```
add_action('init', 'my_initialization');
function my_initialization() {
    //Do the check
}
```

Runs after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent. Useful for intercepting `$_GET` or `$_POST` triggers.

Comment: Where should I put it? I mean which file?

Comment: In your `functions.php` in your current theme directory.

Answer (score -1):

I found some solutions from the answers on this topic. But I found another way myself...

I can create a file and put my codes there, then include it at the end of my wp-config.php file, It seems to work fine.

What's your idea?